# NSOperation for drawing UI while parsing data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

Hope you guys can help me :)

In the main thread, I create a NSOperation and add it to a queue. 
What that operation do is connect to a data server with NSURLConnection, save the receivedData and parse it.

**Operation.m**

```
- (void)start
{
    NSLog(@"opeartion for <%@> started.", [cmd description]);

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", m_BOUNDARY] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:_postData];

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (_connection == nil)
        [self finish];
}
```

Then in this NSURL delegate method I parse the data I've just received from server.

**Operation.m**

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self parseItems];
}
```

In the data, I can found items like, for instance, screenItem, CellItem, TextItem that I send to the main thread for drawing them while arriving. (I create a UITableView if an itemTable arrives, or I create a UIWebView if an itemWeb arrives)

Using this for sending item to main thread:

**Operation.m**

```
- (void) parseItems 
{
    while ([_data length] > 0)
    {
        NSInteger type = [self _readByte];

        switch (type) 
        {
            case SCREEN:
            {
                [self _send: [self _readScreen]];
                break;
            } 
            case CELL:
            {
                [self _send: [self _readCell]];
                break;
            } 

            // ... A lot of different items
        }
    }
}

- (void)_send:(CItem*)_item
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newItem" object:_item];
}
```

Then in notification receiver:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void) _newItemArrived:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processItem:) withObject:[notification object] waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

My problem is that the UI is not painted until NSOperation finish. I thought that NSOpertion, being a different thread, would not block the main thread, but believe that is what is happening.

Some tips for this issue?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: I just answered a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158294/nsoperation-mainqueue-issue/13477136#13477136. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `NSOperationQueue`?

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111208/nsoperation-blocks-ui-painting/2112597#2112597) to the question [NSOperation blocks UI painting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111208/nsoperation-blocks-ui-painting) for a simple example of how to update the UI with a notification from an NSOperation running asynchronously on another thread.

**UPDATE**

1. NSURLConnection supports asynchronous connections by itself with a delegate. You should use this. If you have specific issue(s), you should describe those.
2. Check out the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library.
3. If you really want to use this approach, you could trying running NSURLConnection synchronously (using the class method [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI)). Your app would remain responsive since the connection is on a background thread. However, you would not be able to update anything until all the data is received.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

yes, i'm using NSOperationQueue. I've read that answer, and is just what im doing, but doesnt works. I must be missing something and i cant see it. :S

Comment: Why are you forcing the start method from Operation to run on the main thread?

Comment: Also, the way you are using NSURLConnection is for an asynchronous download, you do not need a separate thread. You just need to implement the delegate methods.

Comment: Mmm, I've tried that, without NSOPeration, but I have not got the result I need. I keep trying, I'll tell you if I found some way.
Thanks gerry!

Comment: Can you provide more details? What did not work about NSURLConnection by itself?

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is a pretty old question but I ran into the same issue and after hours of going through documentation and blogs I found a great solution in this post from Wim Haanstra http://www.depl0y.com/?p=345

Putting your NSOperation in an infinite loop until you get data back should do the trick!